# How do I autogenerate confirmation number in SQLServer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need to autogenerate an order confirmation number with SQL Server 2008 and display it on a webpage.  I have set a column called confirmationnumber and assigned it a uniqueidentifier. Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

I use guids for this purpose. However, I like to have a shorter version that is a bit easier on the eyes. Here is a function that will hash the guid:

```
    public static string GenerateKey()
    {
        long i = 1;
        foreach (byte b in Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray())
        {
            i *= ((int)b + 1);
        }
        return string.Format("{0:x}", i - DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    }
```

The result looks like this:

38f50037b1b56c97

The hash is secure and unique.

Comment: question asked for an option to generate the number in SQL Server 2008. This would need to be installed and executed as a managed DLL on the server or generated in the application code. The number is still a mouthful for a customer to read out to a customer service person with an order enquiry.

Comment: His question says, "with" not "in." However, it is a bit unclear where he wants to handle the generation of the number. Any of the answers to this post will solve the problem depending on the requirements.

Comment: This is only unique on average if you have less than about 4 billion entries. Relying on the uniqueness of a 64bit hash can be a problem in practice.

Answer (score 2):

This really is more of a business question than a technical question.  But while we are on it.. I think the best approach to this problem is to convert a sequential (indentity) order number to a base36 string.  You end of with a nice order number that is both human friendly (think Southwest Airlines) and at the same time obfuscates the potential security issue with sequential order numbers.

just my two cents,

here is a link to base36 algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36

Comment: "at the same time obfuscates the potential security issue with sequential order numbers." Either there is a security issue or there isn't. Base36 encoding doesn't help with that at all.

Answer (score 1):

A uniqueidentifier will produce GUID's. These are 32 characters in length and are not human friendly (think scenario where customer calls up with his reference number). A Guid looks like the following:

f56c41dd-7811-461a-9378-e3a2b095aafc

I would look at using an int with an identity set, this would at least be an easy to use number.

```
CREATE TABLE order (order_id int not null IDENTITY(1,1), customer_code varchar(50) NOT NULL);
```

Then insert the order:

```
DECLARE @order_id int;
INSERT INTO order(customer_code) VALUES('dotnethacker')
SET @order_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

@order_id would then contain the new inserted ID.

Comment: I would never use an identity for a confirmation number that a user can see. Because they are sequential they can be guessed at very easily and are a security risk.

Comment: well if you carry out a check that the customer is linked to the order id they are quoting then you can eliminate the security risk.

Comment: It just depends on how secure you need your solution to be

Answer (score 0):

You can create column of uniqueidentifier type with default NEWID().

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TestTable_id]  DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [id]
```

To catch new inserted GUID, you can use OUTPUT clause:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (id)
OUTPUT inserted.id
VALUES(DEFAULT)
```

**UPDATE:**
To generate code of 10 digits and letters is not a problem. Problem to guarantee uniqueness. To do this, you should to check your table if this code was really unique.

```
    ; with numbers as
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY o1.object_id,o2.object_id) Num,
            LEFT(REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() as nvarchar(40)),'-',''),10) Code 
FROM  sys.objects o1, sys.objects o2)
    SELECT TOP 1 Code FROM numbers where NOT EXISTS(SELECT code FROM  [Table])
```

Comment: This gets me the GUID, but how would I make a shorter and if possible 10 digit confirmation number. Also need to display it on the front end, not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: probably 6 character alphanumeric would be ideal